# Parse.com queryAdapter data Fragment not showing up on actionBar tabs

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse.com query adapter to populate my listview fragment. The data seems to load when I run it, but it only shows lines, not the data.

Also, the data loads perfectly fine when I use the adapter within a  listview Activity.

public class imboard extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

@Override

```
    public android.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

           return  MyFavs.FavInstance();
    }
```

}

public class MyFavs extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


   View myFavView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) myFavView.findViewById(R.id.favList);
    FavoriteAdapter favoriteAdapter = new FavoriteAdapter(getActivity());

    ParseQueryAdapter<CladPost> mainAdapter =
            new ParseQueryAdapter<>(getActivity(), CladPost.class);
    mainAdapter.setTextKey("title");

    listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
    favoriteAdapter.loadObjects();

    return  myFavView;
}
```

}